# Is the number of Kafka partitions accessible when using Camel-Kafka?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka

When using camel-kafka, is there a way to either a) invoke the default Kafka partitioner, and/or b) determine the number of partitions for a topic for use in a partitioning algorithm?  In a Camel Processor I currently have

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY, partition);
```

but I can't choose a value for `partition` without knowing how many partitions are available.  Can I do this with Camel, or do I need to "go native" and invoke `KafkaProducer.partitionsFor`?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  I can invoke the default partitioner simply by omitting to set the `KafkaConstants.PARTITION_KEY` header.

I can use a custom implementation of Partitioner by specifying it as a Camel option:

```
from(...)
    ...
    .to("kafka:{{kafka.host}}:{{kafka.port}}"
        + "?topic={{kafka.topic}}"
        + "&partitioner=my.package.MyPartitioner");
```

and in MyPartitioner I can get the partition info via the `cluster` parameter:

```
@Override
public int partition(String topic,
    Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes,
    Cluster cluster) {

  List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic);

  // use partitions.size()...

  return ...    
}
```